# Using COUNTIFS formulas when linking worksheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, forex

I want to be as detailed as possible.  So Let me provide you with the look of my spreadsheet

```
          Column H       Column Q
Row 11      YES            Win
Row 12       NO            Win
Row 13      YES            Loss
...
...
Row 61      YES            Win
```

The calculation that I used to give me a count of "Winners" is `=COUNTIFS(H11:H61,"YES",Q11:Q61,"Win")` and the one for "Losses" is `=COUNTIFS(H11:H61,"YES",Q11:Q61,"Loss")` - seems to be working well.  However, this calculation is on sheet Input.  I would like to have this calculation done on a totally different sheet entitled Results.  However, my calculation doesn't seem to be working properly.  Here is an example of the calculation I placed on my Results sheet.   `=COUNTIFS(Input!H11:H61,"YES",Q11:Q61,"Win")`.  Any suggestions as to why this might not be working, or maybe a better solution for this problem?

Comment: @CustomX Thanks for presenting my question in a more tangible way.

Comment: You're more than welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the sheet name in all the ranges, i.e.

`=COUNTIFS(Input!H11:H61,"YES",Input!Q11:Q61,"Win")`

Comment: Wow... that simple!  I racked my brain for the last few hours.  LOL

Comment: @BrianWhite - If this solved your problem, it is good for all of us that you accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: New to the group, and didn't know about accepting the answer.  Thanks for pointing that out to me, and my apologies to all for the delay.

Comment: @sancho.s Thanks so much!  I accepted the answer, and have continued to do so on other questions as well.