# Trying to use countif with multiple criteria involving a time range and a set amount

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, forex

Needing to automate results of alerts within certain time frames based on a 24 hour clock (00:00:00).  I believe that a COUNTIF command may be a solution, but not really sure how to use or setup.

Here are my columns that I am trying to use...
E11:E61 - represents my time.  I am looking to pick out those values that fall within 02:00:00 - 06:59:59 from this column.

Then, after filtering that answer.  I need to see which of cells in that time frame equal a win or a loss.  My column for win or losses is Q11:Q61.  That will be one separate field that I will calculate this in.

Then, in another field, I need to calculate a win amount based on whether a cell falls within the time frame and shows a win.  My win amount column is U11:U61.

So, a little more complicated than my experience allows me to solve.  So, I could whatever suggestions or recommendations for solving this.

This has been a great resource for me, and I appreciate everyone's input.

Comment: I think you can get there. Put all your variables in a set of ranges (so they can be easily updated, and the counting formulas are easier to debug). Then take a look at the `COUNTIFS` formula. Just like COUNTIF, but allows multiple criteria. Give it a try and let us know if you get stuck.

Comment: guitarthrower - I am pretty much a novice at this point.  Can you show me an example of what you mean by placing all my variables in a set of ranges, and then how to write the actually COUNTIFS with that information?  I am trying to figure this out, and I must still be missing a piece of the puzzle.   The time element is what is getting me.   My time ranges are based for trading session times (i.e. - London 02:00:00-06:59:59, London & US 07:00:00-10:00:00, and US & After hours 10:01:00-01:59:59* the next day.)

Comment: I can appreciate that you are a novice, but you do have another [question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742762/using-countifs-formulas-when-linking-worksheets) where you demonstrated usage of countifs. Can you show what you have tried? And what it isn't doing for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As guitarthrower suggested in the comments, you could use the `COUNTIFS` function to achieve what you are looking for:

**WINS** `=COUNTIFS(E11:E61,">=2:00:00",E11:E61,"<=6:59:59",Q11:Q61, "WIN")`

**LOSSES** `=COUNTIFS(E11:E61,">=2:00:00",E11:E61,"<=6:59:59",Q11:Q61, "LOSS")`

Comment: I was able to setup a calculation like this... =SUMPRODUCT(--($E$11:$E$61>=AE6),--($E$11:$E$61<=AF6)).   This is because I set up a reference table.     AE3 through AF3 is the London Session.  AE4 through AF4 is the London & USA Session times.  Then, AE5 through AF5 is the USA Session alone.  After this I am having a bit of trouble.  My "After Hours" cells encompass AE6 through AF6 as well as AE7 through AF7.  However, I don't know how to add the After Hours to get the single number of alerts.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @BrianWhite I'm not sure I'm understanding what you have in AE6 through AF7. Can you update your original question to include your new setup?

Comment: Here is an example of the setup I have for London Session

Comment: AE3= 2:00:00   AF3= 06:59:59 (This is the setup for London).  Now my after hours session is a bit more complicated.  I had to setup up two different rows because the trading sessions don't fall equally in line with the 24 hour clock.  So, here is what I have had to do with the After Hours setup...

Comment: AE6=4:00:01  AF6=23:59:59  & then AE7=0:00:00  AF7=01:59:59  which goes right up to the London session open at 2:00:00.  I hope this helps.